# In OpenRefine, how to find/replace initials with regex?

Tags: openrefine

I have a list of names with initials that I want to change from e.g. "Brown, John||Smith, J S" to "Brown, John||Smith, J. S."

I think the way to do this in OpenRefine is by Edit cells/Replace. Then in "Replace" using regex:

Find: 
`(\,\s[A-Z]\s[A-Z]\s)`

Replace with:
`(\,\s[A-Z]\.\s[A-Z]\.\s)`

But it yields: "Brown, John||Smith(,s[A-Z].s[A-Z].s)"

What's missing? Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use part of the 'found' expression in the replace as here, you need to use 'capture groups' to capture the values from the 'find' expression, then use these in the replace - so I think what you need is:

Find: `\,\s([A-Z])\s([A-Z])\s`
Replace: `, $1. $2`

Note that you don't need to use special characters or escaping the replace expression.

However, the danger here is that this is very specific to finding two initials - it will fail for one initial and will lead to incomplete replacement with three or more initials.

You could write a more complex regular expression to deal with different number of initials, but my recommendation would be to use an OpenRefine transformation to do the work. If you did something like

Edit cells -> Transform

then use the GREL

`forEach(value.split(" "),v,if(v.length()==1,v+".",v)).join(" ")`

that would deal with any number of initials. What this does is split the starting string on each space, and then if the length of the 'word' found is 1 (i.e. single character) it will add a period/full stop after it. Then join all the 'words' back together into a string. This could be improved by checking that the 'word' is a single uppercase letter rather than just length==1, but this illustrates the basic approach.

Comment: Amazing! The GREL worked. Thank you so much. Your solution took mere seconds to execute. Very grateful for your help, Owen.